# uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using Facebook Pixel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, facebook-pixel

In my Laravel application I use a Facebook Pixel to do some tracking. One such tracking metric is a form submission.

```js
$("#emailConfirmation").on("submit", function(e) {
  var eventId = {{ $event->id }};

  if (eventId === 87 || eventId === 88 || eventId === 89) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fbq('track', 'Lead', {
      content_name: 'Email confirmation',
      content_category: 'Form submission'
    });

    $("#emailConfirmation").submit();
  }
});
```

What this is meant to do is prevent the form from submitting if the `$event` passed to the view has a particular ID, then send a lead to the Facebook Pixel analytics, and then submit the form.

Instead I get the following error:

> uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: If you are using jquery, you might want to add the tag for it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're creating infinite recursion by raising a `submit` event in the `submit` event handler.

To fix this, raise a submit event of the native `form` Element instead of on the jQuery object:

```js
$("#emailConfirmation").on("submit", function(e) {
  var eventId = {{ $event -> id}};
  if (eventId === 87 || eventId === 88 || eventId === 89) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fbq('track', 'Lead', {
      content_name: 'Email confirmation',
      content_category: 'Form submission'
    });

    this.submit(); // change here
  }
});
```

Comment: No problems :) Happens to us all.

Comment: I didn't even consider that it was already in a submit function, as I thought, right, when that's done I'll just submit the form, I always trip over on the fact you can use `this`